# How can we create Silverlight UserControl as ContainerControl

Tags: silverlight

i need to create UserControl as ContainterControl(Or Template) in silverlight, so that i can use in other Silverlight pages to add controls in it....

Any answer would be appreciable....Thanks GK Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

What you want to create is a `Silverlight Templated Control` (that extend `ContentControl`).

[Sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278064%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) / [Other sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc964292%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

A quick start :

**C# MyControl.cs**

```
public class MyControl: ContentControl
{
    public MyControl()
        : base()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);
    }
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

**XAML MyControl.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:MyControlNsp="clr-namespace:My.Control.NameSpace">
    <Style TargetType="UserToolkit:WarningBar">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyControlNsp:MyControl">
                    <Border>
                            <ContentControl
                                x:Name="content"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Edit :**
You can use [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with a collection if different controls :

```
var myControl = new ItemsControl();
myControl.Items.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "My text block" });
myControl.Items.Add(new CheckBox { Content = "My check box" });
// Or with a collection of items
ObservableCollection<object> controls = new ObservableCollection<object>();
controls.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "My text block" });
controls.Add(new CheckBox { Content = "My check box" });
var myControl2 = new ItemsControl();
myControl2.ItemsSource = controls;
```

Comment: thanks Tonio, but this way I can only Add one CONTROL in the template..what if My template need to be get the multiple control i.e. text box, radio button, list box etc. in each row vertically..each row should be able to get a label and control inside it when template is applied on the page

Comment: If I understand you want to use [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: yes.... but even if i create template using ItemsControl, still I'm able to pass only one Control(e.g. text box, check box etc.)...how can i pass multiple number of control in stack i.e. each row has a control

Comment: I do not know if I understand but look, I edited my answer. I send many type in `Items` of `ItemsControl`.